# Rails internationalization issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have the following file structure:

```
models/modules/survey/survey.rb
```

and

```
controllers/modules/survey/surveys_controller.rb
```

I am having the internationalization for `Survey` model working:

```
pl:
  activerecord:
    models:
      'modules/survey/survey':
        one: Ankieta
        few: Ankiet
        #...
        errors:
          answers_required: 'Wymagana liczba poprawnych odpowiedzi to: %{required_number}, a liczba zaznaczonych odpowiedzi to: %{given_number}'
    attributes:
      'modules/survey/survey':
        type: Typ
        name: Nazwa
        # more attributes
```

But I can't get controller's translation to work.

Neither this:

```
pl:
  'modules/survey/surveys':
    index:
      header: Lista Ankiet
      # ...
```

Nor this:

```
pl:
  modules:
    'survey/surveys':
      index:
        header: Lista Ankiet
        # ...
```

works..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, right after posting this I found the solution - I had to nest everything one under another:

```
pl:
  modules:
    survey:
      surveys:
        index:
          header: Lista Ankiet
          # ...
```